# pi-audit error when executing/ file not found?

Tags: python, security, testing, file-not-found, errno

Hi I run the command below but reieve the error- I have changed the file permission to read and write but not sure why pip-audit cannot find the file?

`python pip-audit -r ./requirements.txt`

`python: can't open file 'C:\Users\XYZ\dev\docs\python-data\datapractise\pip-audit': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Anyhelp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running :

```bash
python -h
```

you get :

`usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg]`

In your case, you are pointing python to pip-audit, which it considers a file, while you have to run pip-audit as follows :

```bash
# run the main module as a script
python -m pip-audit -r requirements.txt

# or use the command directly : 
pip-audit -r requirements.txt
```